# If between two numbers

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to check if a number is between two other numbers using Javascript. I thought I could just use the code below, but it does not work.

```
if (5 > randomNum10 > 0) {
  // ... Do Something
}
```

Comment: Because in JavaScript you can't do `if (5 > randomNum10 > 0)`. You'd need `if (randomNum10 < 5 && randomNum > 0)`

Comment: Is your javascript written within <script> tags?

Comment: :(, I just started programming my first real mini pure javascript application. :(

Comment: The idea behind the question isn't inherently bad, it's the fact that it's very easy to figure out why it doesn't work. In simple cases like this, consider just opening the console (F12) and typing the javascript command in to see the output.

Comment: ok I'll do that next time, sorry for the newb question. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AND between more comparisons:

```
function change(){

  randomNum10 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

      if (5 > randomNum10 && randomNum10 > 0) {
        alert('hi')
      } else if (8 > randomNum10 && randomNum10 > 4) {
        alert('hello')
      } else if (11 > randomNum10 && randomNum10 > 7) {
        alert('yes')
      }

}
```

Comment: you need no check for smaller values, if the value is, for example, `6`, then the first check is `false`, the second without `randomNum10 > 4` `true`, because the forner check would be true in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could check with one value only starting from the smallest and return if found.

```js
function change() {
    var randomNum10 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1),
        textField = document.getElementById('myTextField');

    if (randomNum10 < 5) {
        textField.value = 'hi ';
        return;
    }
    if (randomNum10 < 8) {
        textField.value = 'hello';
        return;
    }
    textField.value = 'yes';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myTextField" />
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()" />
```